# What subnet/netmask for OpenVPN server config on Tomato router?

Tags: networking, router, openvpn, tomato

I am setting up my Freshtomato router as OpenVPN server. The IP range of my router is 192.168.x.x/24. 
However, In the OpenVPN server configuration on this router the subnet/netmask is pre-set to 10.6.0.0/255.255.255.0 Do I have to change this to make the VPN work? I want to access the NAS on my private network at home and to use the VPN for surfing internet when on “remote unsafe network”.

Comment: What isn't working? You should be able to connect to the OpenVPN remotely, and be given a 10.6.0.0/24 address, and then connect to the NAS via IP address and surf the Internet using the default configuration.

Comment: I agree with @acejavelin. It defaults to placing the new ip outside of a typical /24 range, but that shouldn't prohibit you from accessing anything explicitly by ip.

Comment: It is working! Thx Topic can be closed